# lateinit property has not been initialized [kotlin + dagger 2]

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am trying to use dependency injection to use datastore API.
[Datastore API](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/datastore)

I've come up with this article on medium.
[Link](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/datastore-and-dependency-injection-ea32b95704e3)

**Problem**

I can't inject my dataStorePref class to my IntroScreen class which is a library in android
I am using (@Inject lateinit var) and i get lateinit property has not been initialized in runtime.
[app intro](https://github.com/AppIntro/AppIntro#getting-started-)

**DataStoreModule**

```
private const val SETTING = "Setting"

@Module
object DataStoreModule {

    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideDataStorePrefs(appContext: Context) : DataStore<Preferences>{
        return PreferenceDataStoreFactory.create(
            corruptionHandler = ReplaceFileCorruptionHandler(
                produceNewData = { emptyPreferences() }
            ),        
            migrations = listOf(SharedPreferencesMigration(appContext, setting)),
            scope = CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO + SupervisorJob()),
            produceFile = {appContext.preferencesDataStoreFile(SETTING)}
        )
    }
}
```

**DataStorePrefs**

```
class DataStorePrefs
@Inject constructor(
    private val dataStore: DataStore<Preferences>
) {

    private val IS_USER_NEW = booleanPreferencesKey("is_done_with_intro_screen")

    suspend fun saveIsUserNew(boolean : Boolean){
        dataStore.edit { preferences ->
            preferences[IS_USER_NEW] = boolean
        }
    }

    val getIsUserNew : Flow<Boolean> =
        dataStore.data.map { preferences ->
            preferences[IS_USER_NEW] ?: true
    }
}
```

**IntroScreen (this is where i get the error)**

```
class IntroScreen: AppIntro() {

    @Inject 
    lateinit var dataStorePrefs: DataStorePrefs

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {

        lifecycleScope.launch{
            dataStorePrefs.getIsUserNew.collectLatest { isNew ->

                if(isNew){
                    return@collectLatest
                }

                MyApplication.isUserNew = isNew
                MainActivity.startActivity(this@IntroScreen)
                finish()
            }
        }
```

**Stacktrace**

```
 kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property dataStorePrefs has not been initialized
        at com.adonis.fakeshop.ui.onboarding.IntroScreen.getDataStorePrefs(IntroScreen.kt:19)
        at com.adonis.fakeshop.ui.onboarding.IntroScreen$onCreate$1.invokeSuspend(IntroScreen.kt:24)
        at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DispatchedContinuationKt.resumeCancellableWith(DispatchedContinuation.kt:367)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable(Cancellable.kt:30)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.intrinsics.CancellableKt.startCoroutineCancellable$default(Cancellable.kt:25)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.CoroutineStart.invoke(CoroutineStart.kt:110)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.AbstractCoroutine.start(AbstractCoroutine.kt:126)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch(Builders.common.kt:56)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch(Unknown Source:1)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt__Builders_commonKt.launch$default(Builders.common.kt:47)
        at kotlinx.coroutines.BuildersKt.launch$default(Unknown Source:1)
        at com.adonis.fakeshop.ui.onboarding.IntroScreen.onCreate(IntroScreen.kt:23)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8051)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8031)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1329)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3608)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3792)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:103)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2210)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:201)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:288)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7839)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this would work, but based on the the GitHub repo, you create an Activity and extend the `AppIntro()`, can you try annotating `IntroScreen` with `@AndroidEntryPoint`?

```
@AndroidEntryPoint
class IntroScreen: AppIntro() {…}
```